# What is the relationship between the size of a slit and wavelength in diffraction?

Tags: waves, diffraction, wavelength

Almost everywhere I see the statement that diffraction gets stronger when the size of the slit is comparable to the wavelength. I would just like to know the logic behind. Could anyone help me please?
I really need a simple and concise explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient prior effort.